# Freemaker template not render on first time

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

i am using freemaker with spring boot.
every thing is working fine expect one.
when i am sending request and returning to user
it is showing that resource not found.
but when i am restarting my server
and refresh my browser it is working fine.

here is my rest controller method

```java
@GetMapping("/activation")
public ModelAndView activateUser(@RequestParam(value="token") String token) {
    LOGGER.info("inside @class UserController @method activation entry..");
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String msg = userService.activateUser(token);
    if(msg != null) {
        model.put("error", true);
        model.put("message", msg);
    }else {
        model.put("error", false);
        model.put("message", UtilMessages.USER_ACTIVATION_SUCCESS);
    }
    return new ModelAndView("user-activation-response",model);
}
```

also i am using @RestController but it is also behaving same with @Controller.

and my application property configuration as.

```
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path: classpath:/templates

spring.freemarker.suffix: .ftl
```

also when i am sending mail it is working fine with java mail.

Comment: You are saying after restart the template is found. Does that mean that you have added the template while the application was running? (Or else it was already "restarted" at the first attempt as well.) Also, it might be useful to see what FreeMarker logs about the issue.

Comment: no i have not added template while the application is running. i solved this by compile and template at server and send respose as text.

Comment: I think you will need to narrow down what's exactly need for the page to be found. You have mentioned both restarting (shouldn't matter based on what you said), and browser refresh.

Comment: no its is working when i restart server and than refresh the same page. and thanks for you help..;)